# Is there a way to disable arithmetic operators on a specific type in Ada?

Tags: types, ada, gnat

I would like to define HTML response status code numbers as a type but disallow arithmetic operators because it wouldn't make sense for them.

```
type Status_Code is range 100 .. 599;

function "+" (Left, Right : Status_Code) return Status_Code is
begin
      pragma Assert (1 = -1);
      return Left + Right;
end;
```

The code snippet above on GNAT will give an error saying assertion will fail on runtime, but that is false when I add two of the numbers together. Is there a way to force a compiler error or at least a warning when arithmetic attempted on a type like this?

Comment: It should be clear from the fact that you're asking this that the concept you're implementing is not numeric. It's defined as numeric because that's the lowest common denominator among languages. Given the greater expressiveness of Ada, your implementation of the concept should not be (visibly) numeric.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter are you saying I should implement the status codes using an enumeration type instead? Should I just provide a function that lets you get the status code numbers and text values from that enumeration too?

Comment: An enumeration type is one way to approach it. You'd use literals like `OK`, `Not_Found`, and so on. A private type is another approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare it as abstract:

```ada
function "+" (Left, Right : Status_Code) return Status_Code is abstract;
```